# Custom MongoDB codec for JTS (GeoTools)?

Tags: java, mongodb-java, geotools, jts

I'm experimenting with a Java client to store spatial data in MongoDB, however I'm hitting the exception:

```
org.bson.codecs.configuration.CodecConfigurationException: Can't find a codec for class com.vividsolutions.jts.geom.Point.
```

I guess my Java client doesn't include a codec for the JTS classes. I thought such a library would exist as it seems like a fairly common thing to want to do. I haven't found anything that is obviously (to me at least) what I'm looking for.

Does such a thing exist? If so, is there a dependency I can add to my pom.xml file to include this functionality? Or do I have to write my own codec?

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[GeoTools](http://geotools.org) provides an unsupported [mongodb-plugin](http://docs.geotools.org/latest/userguide/library/data/mongodb.html) which should provide this functionality. You need to add

```
<dependency>
   <groupId>org.geotools</groupId>
   <artifactId>gt-mongodb</artifactId>
   <version>${geotools.version}</version>
 </dependency>
```

to your pom and add the following repository.

```
  <repository>
      <id>osgeo</id>
      <name>Open Source Geospatial Foundation Repository</name>
      <url>http://download.osgeo.org/webdav/geotools/</url>
  </repository>
```

**Note** this is an unsupported module so it may be lacking documentation and functionality. So feedback on the user list would be helpful and PRs most useful.

Comment: Thanks - I should have mentioned that I found this but I didn't pursue it as it is unsupported. There was no indication that using it was recommended. I'll read into this but three's no guarantee I'll get the time to implement it. As a side note, I am able to write a JSONObject instead of the POJO instance and for now that will work until I get a working codec.

Comment: I've marked your reply as the answer because I think it is the only real answer to the question, based on my searches. Writing a JSONObject is an alternative as I mentioned.